# Flutter( The argument type 'Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)'.)

Tags: flutter, widget, arguments

```dart
child: Center(
    child: MaterialButton(onPressed: (){
      Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder:(){
              return MyApp();
      } ),);
```

[image]

It is showing this error

> The argument type 'Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)'.
> can anyone tell me why how to resolve this

i have given code above which is showing error and i am expecting someone to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the builder parameter is looking for a Widget Function(Buildcontext) but you are giving it a Function. The difference being that you need to send the context to the next widget.
so try something like:

```
child: Center( child: 
  MaterialButton(onPressed: (){
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => MyApp();
  } 
 ),);
```